# Dual boot with windows 8 (raid)

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, raid

I know there are quite a lot of other posts like these, but I really read all of them and I still couldn't solve my problem.

I recently got a dell with a 1TB hdd disk and a 32gb ssd disk (using RAID) installed with windows 8 and now I want to install ubuntu 13.04 in the hdd disk.

The problem is that it seems that ubuntu can`t recognize the partitions on the drive.
When I start ubuntu installation, no partitions are shown:
http://postimg.org/image/otkjg28ot/

And if I try to open Gparted I get the following error:
http://postimg.org/image/q9w1y7blp/

And clicking in cancel, it recognizes the disk as an unallocated disk.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: See the instructions over here:

[Installing Ubuntu 13.04 on a MSATA SSD][1]

  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/331676/installing-ubuntu-13-04-on-a-msata-ssd

Comment: @Phoeey comments don't support that kind of markdown. Please check the format help. If you want to add links you must use `[text](link)`

Answer (score 1):

The Intel Matrix Storage fakeraid SSD caching setup is unsupported in Linux.  You will have to destroy the raid and use the disks independently to dual boot.

Comment: So if I want to install it in dualboot, I would not be able to use this fakeRAID setup in Windows? If not, is there a way that I could split the hdd disk in two, and then set up one partition to work with the SSD and install ubuntu in the other one?

Comment: @FernandoSantos, I'm not sure if the Intel software can be set up to cache only one partition, but if it can, that probably would work and allow Ubuntu to be installed on the other partition, but it wouldn't be able to access the Windows partition.

Answer (score 0):

Just to post my solution. I entered in Windows 8 and disabled the raid by disabling the Aceleration function in the Intel software. Once I did that, the raid was disabled and then ubuntu could recognize the partitions of the hard drive. Then I installed ubuntu, and then later reactivated the RAID for windows.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can choose "something different" in the installation dialog. But for this, first make a partition in windows and select it in Ubuntu. So i got Ubuntu 13.04 on my windows8 pre-installed laptop.

Comment: But it doesn't appear to me this screen for choosing "something different". 

It first appear the screen to select language, then the one for confirming you are connected to internet and plugged in, and right after this one it appears this one I sent in the screen shot.

Att.,

Comment: His main problem is that he got a fakeRAID, not that he's using Windows 8.